# Writing pipeable function in dplyr syntax, using enquo(), not returning intended output

Tags: r, dplyr, lazy-evaluation, tidyr

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
library(janitor) 

word_count <- function(data, char_col) {
  char_col <- enquo(char_col)

  data %>% 
    select(!!char_col) %>% 
    mutate(char_col = str_remove_all(!!char_col, '[[:punct:]]')) %>% 
    mutate(char_col = str_split(!!char_col, ' ')) %>% 
    separate(char_col, into = paste0('col', 1:30), fill = 'right') %>% 
    select(-col1) %>% 
    gather(value = word) %>% 
    select(word) %>% 
    remove_empty(c('rows')) %>%
    filter(word != '') %>% 
    mutate(word = str_to_lower(word)) %>% 
    group_by(word) %>% 
    summarize(freq = n()) %>% 
   arrange(desc(freq))
}

iris %>% 
  as.tibble() %>% 
  mutate(Species = str_c(Species, ' species')) %>% 
  word_count(Species)
```

This code works as intended outside of a function, but when I use it inside of a function it will return the frequencies of each word and of each 'non-split' string.

I assume this is a problem with how I'm placing the '!!' operators, but I'm not able to solve this by trial and error placement with them. It may also be a lazyeval issue, which I'm not certain how to solve.

I want the output of the function to match the output of the code below.

```
iris %>% 
  as.tibble() %>% 
  mutate(Species = str_c(Species, ' species')) %>% 
  select(Species) %>% 
  mutate(Species = str_remove_all(Species, '[[:punct:]]')) %>% 
  mutate(Species = str_split(Species, ' ')) %>% 
  separate(Species, into = paste0('col', 1:30), fill = 'right') %>% 
  select(-col1) %>% 
  gather(value = word) %>% 
  select(word) %>% 
  remove_empty(c('rows')) %>%
  filter(word != '') %>% 
  mutate(word = str_to_lower(word)) %>% 
  group_by(word) %>% 
  summarize(freq = n()) %>% 
  arrange(desc(freq))
```

Comment: Please add `library(janitor)` as I get  `Error in remove_empty(., c("rows")) : could not find function "remove_empty"`

Comment: Will do, forgot about that one. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We cannot assign a `char_col` object as column name to `mutate`.  It needs to be evaluated.  The `char_col` is a `quosure` object which can be converted to `character` (`quo_name(char_col)`) or `symbol` that when evaluated (`!!`) will assign (`:=`) the correct column name

```
 word_count <- function(data, char_col) {
  char_col <- enquo(char_col)
  char_colC <- quo_name(char_col)

  data %>% 
    select(!!char_col) %>% 
    mutate(!!char_colC := str_remove_all(!!char_col, '[[:punct:]]')) %>% 
    mutate(!!char_colC := str_split(!!char_col, ' ')) %>% 
    separate(char_colC, into = paste0('col', 1:30), fill = 'right') %>%
    select(-col1) %>% 
    gather(value = word) %>% 
    select(word) %>% 
    remove_empty(c('rows')) %>%
    filter(word != '') %>% 
    mutate(word = str_to_lower(word)) %>% 
    group_by(word) %>% 
    summarize(freq = n()) %>% 
    arrange(desc(freq))
}

out2 <- iris %>%
           as.tibble() %>%
           mutate(Species =str_c(Species, ' species')) %>%
           word_count(Species)
```

-checking the output without using the function

```
out1 <- iris %>% 
          as.tibble() %>% 
          mutate(Species = str_c(Species, ' species')) %>% 
          select(Species) %>% 
          mutate(Species = str_remove_all(Species, '[[:punct:]]')) %>% 
          mutate(Species = str_split(Species, ' ')) %>% 
          separate(Species, into = paste0('col', 1:30), fill = 'right') %>% 
          select(-col1) %>% 
          gather(value = word) %>% 
          select(word) %>% 
          remove_empty(c('rows')) %>%
          filter(word != '') %>% 
          mutate(word = str_to_lower(word)) %>% 
          group_by(word) %>% 
          summarize(freq = n()) %>% 
          arrange(desc(freq)) 


identical(out1, out2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks! One semi-related question. How can I write an error message that checks if data$char_col is a character vector?

Comment: @ChristopherPeralta  You can use `summarise_if/mutate_if` to check whether the column to change is a character vector or not.  If you wanted to get some error message, then you can check `possibly`

Comment: I added 'select_if(is.character) %>%' in the function, then wrapped it in possibly(). Thanks!